# whether the inverse operator of identity plus projection is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $a\in H$, and $C$ be a nonempty closed convex set, which may not contains $a$. Denote by $P_C$  the projection operator in $H$ onto $C$. I would like to study whether the inverse of the operator $A: y\mapsto y+P_C(y-a)$ is bounded.

---

Since the projection operator is monotone, I have shown that $A$ is bijective, thus $A^{-1}$ is well-defined on $H$. However, I don't know whether $A^{-1}$ is bounded.

I have tried to show for some $\alpha\in (0,1)$, $y\mapsto \alpha y+P_C(y-a)$ is semi-positive, but due to the existence of $a$, I failed to prove the desired inequality, even if I add a further assumption that 
$0\in int(C).$

So is the inverse operator bounded? Or under what assumption it is bounded?

Comment: Simple observation, for projection $P$ we have $(I + P)^{-1} = I - \tfrac{1}{2}P$, which should generally be bounded.